How to use SwiftData #Index with < iOS 18 compatibility
I want to use iOS 18's #Index in an app that still supports iOS 17.
This doesn't work:
@Model
final class MyModel {
    if #available(iOS 18, *) {
        #Index<MyModel>([\.prop1, \.prop2])
    }

    var prop1: Bool
    var prop2: Bool
}

How can I conditionally use that feature only on iOS 18?

It looks like this can't be done currently , I tried to use @available(iOS 18, *) but that clashed with the @Model macro and we can't move the #Index macro to an extension either unfortunately.
